# how to include javascript content in local variables or give a namespace locally

Tags: javascript, oop

Suppose I have included 2 javascripts X and Y and both of them contains a commanNameFunction having different functionality. I don't have permission to change the content of script X and Y so that I can apply modular pattern there. Now the problem is that previously declared function in X is getting overridden by Y. Is there any way I can have access to both the function while including them in another javascript. Like

```
var x = <script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript" src="X.js"></script>
var y = <script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript" src="Y.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tried getting a reference to your function after loading X, saving it in another function, then loading Y?

Comment: again if I have to access X function then??

Comment: See below in answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the function name is `commanNameFunction`, try this as a terrible hack assuming you can't change contents.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript" src="X.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript">
    var commanNameFunctionFromX = commanNameFunction;
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/JavaScript" src="Y.js"></script>
```

Now if you need to call `commanNameFunction`, you can call it as:

```
commanNameFunctionFromX()
```

If you need to do this for an entire script, you'd probably be better off trying to detect new objects. Warning: This is very hacky, and will no doubt have terrible effects if you're overriding any predefined functions.

First we save the original variables - run this before loading any scripts.

```
var existing = [];

for (var i in window) { 
 existing.push(i)
}
```

Then you load a script, save any new functions / objects to a specified namespace, using the list of already existing objects. This function will mostly do that, with the previous hack warnings.

```
function saveNewToNamespace(existing, X) {
  for (var i in window) { 
    if (window[i] && existing.indexOf(i) == -1) {
       console.log("new: " + i);
       X[i] = window[i];
       window[i] = undefined;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, after each new script, declare a new variable and load new functions into it.

```
var X = {};
saveNewToNameSpace(existing, X);
```

Comment: What i wrote was just an instance. Actually I have 2 huge java scrips having many things common.

Comment: I'll expand a little to make this more general.

Comment: @Ninja I've expanded the answer to make it more general for a script. It's a terrible hack though that I wouldn't recommend.